# Accessing ParentViewController from UITextFields inside a custom View

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I have a UIScrollView to which I append multiple custom UIView's that contain UITextFields...

In each of these text fields I handle the EditingChanged event so that I do some calculations and append them to a UILabel...

Now... Outside my UIScrollView I have a TextBox who's value I need to access from the TextFields inside my custom View...

Can I scroll up the hierarchy and find that control by it's tag somehow? I've tried using ParentViewController but that's always null.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `.superview` property to walk up the view hierarchy to the top level `UIView`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/superview

Answer (score 0):

Is the TextBox outside the UIScrollView in the same UIViewController? You should be using a controller to manage the communication. Handle the EditingChanged in the lowest level that contains both text boxes. So, if they are in the same UIViewController, have it handle the EditingChanged and have a reference to the text box as well.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use UIApplicationDelegate.

1. Declare an instance referring to UISCrollView, and set UIScrollView to the instance.

   @interface YourAppDelegate  {
       YourUIScrollView* yourScrollView;
   }
   @property (nonatomic, retain) YourUIScrollView* yourScrollView;
   @end
2. Wherever you want to access the scrollview, you can do as below,

   YouUIScrollView* yourScrollView =  ((YourAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedapplication] delegate]).yourScrollView;

Comment: Hmm now I somehow need to translate that into MonoTouch (C#)!

Answer (score 0):

You could go the other way and go down the hierarchy to get the value from the lower `UITextField` and perform the calculation outside of the `UIScrollView`. A way you could access the lower `UITextField`'s is as follows:

```
foreach (scrollView.ViewWithTag(tagNum).SubViews.OfType<UITextField>())
{
  // get the value from the textfield then perform the required calculation
}
```

(this of course assumes that you've given the the `UIView`'s you're adding a Tag.